# How to load .jar file in C++ using JNI

Tags: c++

I am trying to load a method present in a .jar. Following is code snippet

```
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];

options[0].optionString =
      "-  Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\Desktop\\POC\\POC\\Debug\\Sample2.jar;    
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
m_Status = JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr (&m_JVM, (void**)&m_JavaEnv, &vm_args);
```

But when I use the

```
     classForJava = m_JavaEnv->FindClass ("Sample2");
```

`classForJava` contains `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify full name of the class including package name with `.` replaced with `/`.
For exampe if your `Sample2` class is in `org.test` package, use `m_JavaEnv->FindClass ("org/test/Sample2");`

By the way, it might be a typo but  the `optionString` space between `-` and `Djava.class.path` should be removed.